# Streaming I/O in c++

Tags: c++, file, io

I am trying to get this file stream program to work but when I run it all that happens is it outputs "Writing" instead of outputting the file. What am i doing wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char str[10];
  ifstream b_file ( "ioTest.txt" );
  b_file>> str;
  cout<< str <<"\n";
  cin.get(); 

}
```

Comment: Most likely "Writing" is the first whitespace separated token in your `ioTest.txt`.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Look at the docs for ifstream. [Here is one source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/). 
I presume you want to 'get' a whole 'line' from the file. That's a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard input streams use whitespace as a delimiter for input. If you try extracting to a string, it will extract every character until a whitespace character is found. If you need the entire content of the file, here are a few options:

#### `while (in >> word)`

```
while (b_file >> word)
{
    std::cout << word;
}
```

This method will iterate over each whitespace-separated tokens in the input stream.

#### `std::getline()`

```
while (std::getline(b_file, line))
{
    std::cout << line;
}
```

`std::getline()` retrieves line-wise input, meaning it will extract every character until it reaches a delimiter. The delimiter by default is the newline but it can be specified as a third argument.

---

#### `std::istream_iterator<T>`

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(b_file),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

`std::istream_iterator` is a special-purpose stream iterator class designed to "iterate" over tokens of type `T` from an input stream.

#### `rdbuf()`

```
std::cout << b_file.rdbuf();
```

This is more low-level. An overload of `std::ostream::operator<<()` takes a stream buffer pointer as an argument, and it will extract characters directly from the buffer.